# Removing font color from html string

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I have a simple html string like:

```
<p dir="ltr"><a href="xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj" class="favourite" data="MeTdMw9Ndj"><font color="#009a49">Good evening</font></a></p>
```

I want the output to be:

```
 <p dir="ltr"><a href="xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj" class="favourite" data="MeTdMw9Ndj">Good evening</a></p>
```

What should the do to achieve the same?

My attempt:

```
//removing font tags
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webText);
        Elements elements = doc.select("font");

        //remove all 'font'-tags
        elements.remove();
        webText = doc.toString();
```

Comment: @nhahtdh I can use any, my JSOUP way was not giving the required output, so I tried out the regex way.

Comment: @kittu88: You can check out my answer using Jsoup. It is not more complex than the regex answer.

Comment: Check my update it fillup this case `<FONT \n color="red" > test </font>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use regex, you can use: `<\\/{0,1}font.*?>`

```
String html = "<p dir='ltr'><a href='xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj' class='favourite' 
                data='MeTdMw9Ndj'><font color='#009a49'>Good evening</font></a></p>";
html = html.replaceAll("<\\/{0,1}font.*?>","");
System.out.println(html);
```

Output:

```
<p dir='ltr'><a href='xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj' class='favourite'
 data='MeTdMw9Ndj'>Good evening</a></p>
```

Check the [**demo here**](http://ideone.com/btDssz)

Comment: So, downvoted because I'm using regex? clearly OP put `regex` tag in the question

Comment: It's never a good idea to process HTML with regex. OP finally uses Jsoup, so even more of the reason to move away from regex solution.

Comment: @nhahtdh Okay, not sure exactly why its not a good idea. but since OP is ok with this solution, then I'll just leave this answer here :)

Comment: It is not replace `uppercase` tag..  and `newline tag` like `<FONT \n color="red" > test </font>`

Answer (score 3):

You only need to take all the child nodes of the `font` nodes with [`Node.childNodes()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes%28%29), and append it to the parent node with [`Element.insertChildren(int index, Collection<? extends Node> children)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#insertChildren%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29) after the index `font` nodes (which can be retrieved with [`Node.siblingIndex`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#siblingIndex%28%29)).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webText);
Elements elements = doc.select("font");

for (Element e: elements) {
    e.parent().insertChildren(e.siblingIndex(), e.childNodes());
}

elements.remove();
webText = doc.toString();
```

I have tested the code on Java 7, with different versions of Jsoup - 1.7.2, 1.7.3 and 1.8.1. All of them produces the expected result.

This is my test code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SO27854788 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening <font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening</font> <font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening <font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening</font></font> <font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening</font></font><p dir=\"ltr\"><a href=\"xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj\" class=\"favourite\" data=\"MeTdMw9Ndj\"><font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening</font></a></p><p dir=\"ltr\"><a href=\"xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj\" class=\"favourite\" data=\"MeTdMw9Ndj\"><font color=\"#009a49\">Good evening. Here are some <span>more tags inside</span></font></a></p>");
        Elements elements = doc.select("font");

        for (Element e: elements) {
            e.parent().insertChildren(e.siblingIndex(), e.childNodes());
        }

        elements.remove();

        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  Good evening Good evening Good evening Good evening Good evening
  <p dir="ltr"><a href="xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj" class="favourite" data="MeTdMw9Ndj">Good evening</a></p>
  <p dir="ltr"><a href="xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj" class="favourite" data="MeTdMw9Ndj">Good evening. Here are some <span>more tags inside</span></a></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: output: <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  null
 </body>
</html>

Comment: @kittu88: Which version of JSoup are you using?

Comment: 1.7.3 jar file I am using

Comment: @kittu88: I tested my snippet with Jsoup versions from 1.7.2 to 1.8.1. All of them produces the expected result on Java 6 and Java 7.

Comment: @kittu88: Not sure what your problem was, but I have added the test cases I wrote before answering.

Answer (score -1):

By regex: search pattern `(?i)<\\/?font[^>]*>`  and replace with `""`

```
        String cleanstr = "<p dir='ltr'><a href='xxxx://viewstudent/MeTdMw9Ndj' class='favourite' data='MeTdMw9Ndj'><font color='#009a49'>Good evening</font></a></p>";
        cleanstr = cleanstr.replaceAll("(?i)<\\/?font[^>]*>", "");
        System.out.println(cleanstr);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/OV1Ebt)